# rendering obj files in two different positions

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering

I need to load a building over its terrain which is available as two different .obj files.

When i loaded the files they are overlapping. How can i adjust the two different models so that the building is exactly on top of the terrain.

Note: 4582420.obj is the building file and
      4582421.obj is the terrain file

Code snippet for loading the obj models is given below

// load obj models.

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 2; i++ )
{
    char objName[ 256 ];
    char mtlName[ 256 ];


    sprintf_s( objName, "models/sampleA/%d.obj", 4582420 + i );
    std::ifstream ifs( objName );

    if ( ifs.is_open() )
    {

        sprintf_s( mtlName, "models/sampleA/%d.mtl", 4582420 + i );
        CObjLoader* pObjMesh = new CObjLoader();
        pObjMesh->Load( offset, objName, mtlName );

        // if open is ok, the obj model will be pushed into gObjs.
        gObjs.push_back( pObjMesh );
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: what library is this? You should know how to position objects when you already load obj files.

Answer (score 0):

What program are you using for rendering? In general you'll have to provide a transform matrix which contains scale, rotation and translation of each object. Each vertex of the object is then multiplied by the transform matrix to determine its position in world space. This is the so called object space to world space transformation.

Comment: OpenGl is used for rendering

Comment: @user3138452: OpenGL is just an API. Your program is doing the rendering. It's your responsibility to implement the proper transformation for the objects you render.